# Как правильно обратиться к методу в Java?

Tags: java

Выбивает ошибку что метод не существует

**Файл первый:**

```
import edu.san.stats.AverageCalcAware;
import edu.san.stats.MaxMinCalcAware;
import edu.san.stats.MedianCalcAware;

public class BigDecimalStats{

    private int BigDecimal[];


    public BigDecimalStats(int BigDecimal[] ) {
        this.BigDecimal = BigDecimal;
    }


    public class Average implements AverageCalcAware{

        @Override
        public java.math.BigDecimal calcMedian() {
            return null;
        }

    }

    public class MaxMin implements MaxMinCalcAware{

        @Override
        public java.math.BigDecimal calcMax() {

            int max = (int) Double.MIN_VALUE;

            for (int i = 0; i < BigDecimal.length; i++) {
                 max = Math.max(max, BigDecimal[i]);

              }
            return calcMax();
        }

        @Override
        public java.math.BigDecimal calcMin() {
            return null;
        }

    }

    public class Median implements MedianCalcAware{

        @Override
        public java.math.BigDecimal calcAverage() {
            return null;
        }
}
```

**Файл второй (вывод):**

```
public class StatsCalc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] big = {1,2,3,1,5,6};

        BigDecimalStats stats = new BigDecimalStats(big);

        for (int i = 0; i < big.length; i++) {
             System.out.println(big[i] + " ");
          }

        System.out.println(String.format("Max: " + stats.calcMax()));
    }
}
```

Возникает ошибка при вызове `stats.calcMax()`:

> Multiple markers at this line - The method calcMax() is undefined for
>   the type BigDecimalStats - MaxMin cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: А что собственно говоря не так и в чем вопрос?

Comment: Выбивает ошыбку что метод calcMax() не существует, во втором файле

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - The method calcMax() is undefined for the type 
  BigDecimalStats
 - MaxMin cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: можно сделать метод статическим, но все равно работать не будет, так как вызывает сам себя.

Answer (score 2):

Метод `calcMax()` у вас определен в интерфейсе `MaxMinCalcAware`. Этот интерфейс реализован классом `MaxMin`, но не классом `BigDecimalStats`. Вам нужно обращаться к объекту типа `MaxMinCalcAware`, либо реализовать интерфейс в самом классе `BigDecimalStats`.

PS: советую вам не называть переменные класса таким образом:
`private int BigDecimal[];` - уберите из наименования `BigDecimal`

Comment: нужно сперва создать новый обьект интерфейса MaxMinCalcAware?

Comment: нужно реализовать указаные интерфейсы внутри вашего класса `BigDecimalStats` а не создавать вложеные классы, а еще, читать читать и еще раз читать литературу!